# Is the openGL implementation operating-system specific?

Tags: api, opengl

I have understood APIs to be glue between two codes. They are implemented in the form of functions of a library, which is eventually compiled and needed on the computer during the runtime.

So doesn't it mean that their implementation is OS-specific?

I am particularly interested in knowing if an implementation of opengl is OS specific or not? I am using fedora 19 and Mesa library is installed.

Comment: There are standards, like POSIX, which mean APIs aren't OS-specific, however generally "yes".

Comment: The OP asks whether the *implementation* of the API is OS-specific. So POSIX would be a "yes".

Comment: The other thing to remember is that the POSIX API has grey areas (notably in the part dealing with threads) so that for a higher-level API such as Mesa, OS-specific code may be needed to work around the differences in implementations on different platforms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### In general

Some APIs may be implemented in an OS-specific fashion, others not.

It depends on whether low-level features are needed to implement them, or whether the environment in which the API will run provides or doesn't provide the necessary building blocks to implement them.

A JDBC type-4 driver for example, implements the JDBC API in an OS-independent fashion.

Other APIs such as POSIX may have to be implemented in OS-specific ways, while perhaps some parts of them may be implementable in OS-independent fashion.

Another example is APR, the Apache Portable Runtime, which is implemented in an OS-specific way. Another API, Serf is built on top of APR so its implementation is actually OS-independent.

In summary, as a general rule, low-level APIs tend to be implemented in OS-specific ways, while high-level APIs will be implemented in terms of other lower-level APIs and hence more likely to be implemented in an OS-independent manner.

### Mesa/OpenGL

The first section of this answer was written whilst the question was a generic API question. Later the question was changed to be specifically about OpenGL.

I'm not so familiar with the Mesa implementation of OpenGL; I would assume that for maintainability reasons a very substantial part of it is implemented in an OS-independent fashion, but because of A) the need to interface with hardware -- which tends to be done in different ways on different OSes -- and B) the need to achieve good performance there will also be a not-insignificant amount of OS-specific code.

The other thing to remember is that the POSIX API has grey areas (notably in the part dealing with threads) so that for a higher-level API such as Mesa, OS-specific code may be needed to work around the differences in implementations on different platforms.

Comment: Thanks, but if you look at the question's revision history first there was no mention of Mesa or OpenGL.

Comment: Ops... didn't notice it. If you edit I can remove the downvote.

Comment: Done; I've moved my comments into the answer.

Comment: @Colin'tHart  you said "Another example is APR, the Apache Portable Runtime, which is implemented in an OS-specific way. Another API, Serf is built on top of APR so its implementation is actually OS-independent."  APR is OS-specific. Serf needs APR. so doesn't it means that Serf can be used only on the operating systems on which APR is installed? doesn't it make Serf OS-specific?

Comment: Serf itself is implemented in an OS-independent way. It makes use of APR to hide all the differences in underlying OS APIs.

Comment: @Saurabh, you are right that since `Serf` uses `APR`, then it can only run on OSes that have `APR` installed, but that's not what people usually think as OS-specific. A simpler example is the C standard library. If you write code that only uses the C standard library, it's 100% portable. However, if you have a platform that doesn't implement the C library, well you can't say your code is not portable. It's _that_ platform that doesn't have the necessary backbone. In short, if nowhere in your code you have `#ifdef __linux__` or `#ifdef _WIN32` or such, then your code is not OS-specific.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL implementations are, of course, OS specific. They are integrated with the OS, usually with device drivers.

However, the OpenGL specification is OS independent, letting the OpenGL API be not OS specific.

Take care that the OpenGL initialization (windows and rendering context) is very OS dependent (WGL or GLX APIs implementations).

Comment: Side note: for window and input handling, there are also OS-independent libraries, such as [SDL](http://libsdl.org/).